# Empty method in an abstract class

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, static-analysis

I have just installed PMD to analyze my Java project. Really nice tool, highly recommended.
Anyways, I got a few errors saying:

> "An empty method in an abstract class should be abstract instead"

I checked out PMD documentation and the explanation says:

> as developer may rely on this empty implementation rather than code the appropriate one

So I think I understand the reason behind this code style error, but consider the following scenario: I have an abstract class called Entity. This class has a boolean method with default implementation. (controls whether to delete its related entities upon deletion). Only a few of the derived classes override this default behavior to true.

Should I remove the default implementation and force all deriving classes to declare their behavior? 
Do you really think this pattern is such a bad practice?

**Clarification:** PMD treats a method with single return statement as empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's just a guideline. It tells you so that you might want to reconsider your design, but if your design already makes perfect sense, there's no reason to obey a software instead of your brain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 1.8, you can make Entity an **interface** instead of an abstract class and write a **default** implementation for your method in it.

```
public interface Entity {
    default boolean yourMethod() {
        //default implementation ...
    }
}
```

You can use this for reference :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html